# Vector of SumIfs() in R

Tags: r, excel, aggregate, user-defined-functions, sumifs

I am looking to mimic Excel's SumIfs() function in R by creating a mean-if vector of conditional averages for each observation. I've seen a lot of examples that use `aggregate()` or `setDT()` to summarize a data frame based on fixed quantities. However, I'd like to create a vector of these summaries based on the variable inputs of each row in my data frame.

Here is an example of my data:

```
> a <- c('c', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'a')
> b <- c(6, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 4, 3, 3, 5, 5, 4, 6, 6)
> c <- c(69.9, 21.2, 37, 25, 65.9, 33.1, 67, 28.4, 36, 67, 22, 37.9, 62.3, 30, 25)
> df <- data.frame(cbind(a, b, c))
> df$b <- as.numeric(as.character(df$b))
> df$c <- as.numeric(as.character(df$c))
> df
   a b    c
1  c 6 69.9
2  a 1 21.2
3  b 1 37.0
4  a 2 25.0
5  c 1 65.9
6  b 2 33.1
7  c 2 67.0
8  a 4 28.4
9  b 3 36.0
10 c 3 67.0
11 a 5 22.0
12 b 5 37.9
13 c 4 62.3
14 b 6 30.0
15 a 6 25.0
```

I would like to add a fourth column, `df$d`, that takes the average of `df$c` for those observations where `df$a == x & y - 2 <= df$b < y` where `x` and `y` are `df$a` and `df$b`, respectively, for the observation being calculated.

Doing this by hand, `df$d` looks like:

```
> df$d <- c(62.3, NA, NA, 21.2, NA, 37, 65.9, 25, 35.05, 66.45, 28.4, 36, 67, 37.9, 25.2)
> df
   a b    c     d
1  c 6 69.9 62.30
2  a 1 21.2    NA
3  b 1 37.0    NA
4  a 2 25.0 21.20
5  c 1 65.9    NA
6  b 2 33.1 37.00
7  c 2 67.0 65.90
8  a 4 28.4 25.00
9  b 3 36.0 35.05
10 c 3 67.0 66.45
11 a 5 22.0 28.40
12 b 5 37.9 36.00
13 c 4 62.3 67.00
14 b 6 30.0 37.90
15 a 6 25.0 25.20
```

Is there a function I can use to do this automatically? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done in a straightforward way using a left self-join in SQL. This joins to each row of the `u` instance of `df` those rows of the `v` instance of `df` that satisfy the `on` condition and then averages over their `c` values.

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf("select u.*, avg(v.c) as d
       from df u left join df v
       on u.a = v.a and v.b between u.b-2 and u.b-1
       group by u.rowid")
```

giving:

```
   a b    c     d
1  c 6 69.9 62.30
2  a 1 21.2    NA
3  b 1 37.0    NA
4  a 2 25.0 21.20
5  c 1 65.9    NA
6  b 2 33.1 37.00
7  c 2 67.0 65.90
8  a 4 28.4 25.00
9  b 3 36.0 35.05
10 c 3 67.0 66.45
11 a 5 22.0 28.40
12 b 5 37.9 36.00
13 c 4 62.3 67.00
14 b 6 30.0 37.90
15 a 6 25.0 25.20
```

Comment: I was literally just trying to work out how to do this same join with `data.table`. Hadn't come across `sqldf` before, very cool. (+1)

Comment: Thank you both for your help! This is perfect.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use a loop to basically just write out exactly how you described the problem:

```
n <- nrow(df)
d <- numeric(n)

for (i in seq_len(n)) {
  x <- df$a[i]
  y <- df$b[i]
  d[i] <- with(df, mean(c[a == x & y - 2 <= b & b < y]))
}

all.equal(d, df$d)
#> [1] TRUE
```

I don't love this solution, but I couldn't think of a simple way to do this otherwise, because the required grouping isn't disjoint due to the condition for `b`. I'm very curious to see if somebody comes up with a neater way to do this.